# Populate Jlist with data in Swing using the MVC Pattern correctly

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I'm writing an MVC App. I have a JList that I do need to populate with data that is baked on the Model/Controller.

I don't know how to pass the data to the View without breaking the MVC model; this is storing/creating data on the View.

Here is a shrinked and simplified version of my code.

```
// This class receives data and works on it. Is not related to show 
// what it does for the purposes of my question. Just know that the 
// data that I want to show on the JList on the view should be created 
// here.
// 
// public class controller implements Observer{
// }
```

Here is the View :

```
// Imports

    public class View extends JPanel {


        public View() {
            super();

            JList itemList = new JList();
            DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();

            itemList.setModel(listModel);

            listModel.addElement("Element1");
            listModel.addElement("Element2");
            listModel.addElement("Element3");
            listModel.addElement("Element4");
            listModel.addElement("Element5");
            listModel.addElement("Element6");

            itemList.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,40));

            this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
            JButton button = new JButton("New Time");
            JButton button1 = new JButton("New Time2");
            label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 50));

            JPanel group = new JPanel( new GridLayout())
                    ;
            group.add(button);
            group.add(button1);

            JPanel east = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );

            east.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            east.add(itemList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            east.add(group, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            add(east, BorderLayout.EAST);

        }

    }
```

So, in the JList of the view I need to show the items, but I don't know how is the way to populate the JList from the data created on the controller/model. I only know how to add elements the way Im doing on the view, and this is wrong.

I don't know if it is possible to tell the Jlist to use the data created on the controller/model.

Any help is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Try not to forget, Swing is a type of MVC itself (for example, `JList` has a concept of model, it also has a controller inbuilt), so sometimes, it can be difficult to implement a pure MVC.  A pure MVC, would have the controller act as a "date source" which would feed information from the model to the view, but in this kind of case, that's a lot of code duplication which just isn't required.  Depending how you want to do it, you could have the model provide a "list of data" method, which the controller would pass on to the view, which would then wrap it in a `ListModel` for it's own needs

Comment: This means that neither the model or controller care how the the data is been presented, only that the data is presented in some form (could be combobox or table...who cares :P)

Comment: Your JList and it's model are local variables that have been declared within the view's constructor, meaning that there is no way to change its state as the program runs, so as written your code will not work. Use private fields where needed, and give the view appropriate methods to allow the controller to change its state where needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know how to pass the data to the View without breaking the MVC model; this is storing/creating data on the View.

You could make the "controller" a `ListModel`, you could then have it proxy the data from the underlying model, either as another `ListModel` or via the information the original model is providing.

To my mind, this is overkill and wasting a lot of you time.

Swing already implements MVC, all bit more like MV-C, trying to wrap another (pure) MVC on top of it is always going to present issues.

Instead, the model should provide some data, either as an array or `List`, which can past to the view for it to present, in what ever way the view decides is best.

In this case, the view isn't "creating data", because that data is provided by the controller via the model.

No matter what you do, you will find the view has to maintain a reference to the data at some level, for example, a `JTextField` will store data in the form of `String` - it has to, it can't work without doing so.

This is just my opinion, but I've fought these issues before.  Focus on the requirements of the data, focus on how you might communicate with the model, controller and view in a way which decouples each layer from the other (i.e. don't expose UI elements to the controller, it doesn't care "how" it's managed, only that the view promises to provide some information).

This way you can change the implementation of the model, view and/or controller and none of the others should care, it should continue to work

Comment: My guess, he is required to use full MVC, overkill or not for assignment purposes, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I understand your point, and it's ok. I need to have a JList on the view. Then, I need to - automatically - refresh it when a new object is added to the List on the Model. How can I make this on the Controller ? I don't know, really.

Comment: This is starting to get to broad, a please design my mcv type question

Comment: No, in any way. I just don't know how to communicate the View with the Model. I was absolutely honest, you are wrong.

Comment: @CapitanGrantX You need an observer pattern. You model generates some kind of update event, to which your controller registers to and passes into the view. Have a look at the ListModel, it has listener support, you need the same thing

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels My concern with that is, if the op has buttons and text fields, does this mean the controller has to implement the Document and ButtonModel interfaces as well 